# How to create smooth animations (Spine 2D)

Tags: animation, resource-recommendations

Three months ago, I started to work in Unity 2d game development. I am student in electronic engineering and programming, so I like to work on animations in my free time and create games. I also create game textures in photoshop. All in all I'm hobbyist.

But I find it hard to create animations. I work in Spine 2d and I can't create smooth 2d animation. I try to make a working 2d walking animation for my heroes but it ends to be a big fail.

Is there any book, or video tutorial, something very detail, but easy to understand for basic character 2d animation? (ilde, walk, attack, death, etc)
Here are some of my animations for reference:

http://giphy.com/gifs/transparent-3o85xnRVivCxKQITUQ
http://giphy.com/gifs/3o85xpXaRzaKpMdnji

Comment: Hello and welcome, Nikos. Unfortunately we don't  have a large community of members who focus on building things in Unity nor Spine 2d, so you may not get much of a response. Let us know if you have any questions regarding the site!

Comment: @ZachSaucier do you think that I need to post my question in Game Dev ?

Comment: I was going to suggest Game Dev myself.

Comment: @ZachSaucier is there any way to transfer my question to Game Dev or do I need to do it manually?

Comment: @NikosKLon You can flag it for moderator attention listing the request, they can move it for you. They may just have you delete it and ask a new one there, I'm not sure